# Winsorization to remove spikes in time series

Tags: time-series, model-evaluation, winsorizing

In product demand forecasting, is it valid to use winsorization to remove large outliers (spikes) in the data? I understand that the spikes may be due to holiday effects (e.g. people will buy more chocolate during Valentine's day). However, they seem to be skewing the data.

The approach that I intend to adopt is that by [Neal Wagner in *Intelligent techniques for  forecasting multiple time series in real-world systems*](https://cs.adelaide.edu.au/users/zbyszek/Papers/p51.pdf) in which explainable spikes are first removed, then added back in after the modeling task. The paper states that spikes are "removed", but *how* they are removed is never expounded upon. In my case, I intend to use winsorization.

Comment: Holiday effects and seasonality are not generally thought of as "outliers"; they are usually explicitly modeled. Do you have "spikes" for which you have absolutely no pattern/explanation? For those, your model can incorporate effects related to these outliers *after* it has seen them, but you should not first remove them for the entire series, then measure your pseudo-out-of-sample forecast accuracy on the already adjusted data (that would be cheating). Is that the approach you're suggesting?

Comment: Yes, that was what was suggested to me, but it did seem invalid, which is why I doubled checked it here. For spikes that seem spurious and not explainable, how do I go about "incorporating effects related to them" as you state?

Comment: Why do they seem inside invalid? Are the outlets on holidays or not? In your question you said they are.